# apache poi copy from very large xls to new workbook sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have very large xls file , which contains two sheets. I want to combine these two sheets into one and copy to new workbook . But I get out of memory exception when I try to access this large xls as below :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("input.xls"));
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

I tried using event api for xls : http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api
But using that we can only read the cell values . But here I need to copy to new excel sheet.

Comment: Have you increased heap size with `-Xms` and `Xmx` parameters?

Comment: Yes. I tried that and it will not work. I need some other solution through program.

Comment: Please provide some specifics.  What are the sizes of the two workbooks, both in number of cells (H x V) and megabytes.

Comment: File size is 97MB . There are 65k rows.

Comment: That is not a "large" file and it should fit comfortably on most modern systems.  Did you try with `-Xms1G -Xmx2G`?  Can you run this on a system with more memory?  Are you using the 64-bit JVM?

Comment: I cannot run on a system with more memory.

Comment: As [explained in the documentation, don't use an InputStream if you have a File](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) as it uses more memory!

Comment: Can you pls tell me how can I use File for xls?   HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new File("input.xls")); is giving error as "no suitable constructor found"

Answer (score 2):

Apache POI provides a low-memory footprint [SXSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) API to write data to xlsx. It does not load everything in memory at once so it's the solution while working with very large excel files. You may want to consider this.

Comment: I am trying to copy from xls file and SXSSF is for xlsx

Comment: Yes,SXSSF is for excel 2007(xslx)